# How to access Solarized color values within bash script

Tags: macos, bash, bashrc, iterm, solarized

I'm trying to make my `bash` `PS1` prompt colors according to the **Solarized theme**. I have **solarized** installed and working for `iTerm2`, but so far have been unsuccessful in creating a custom PS1 prompt that matches the theme.

I have tried using values such as the following for cyan, but I end up getting either no color or the wrong color.
`\033[0;37m`

I obtained the values above from the following link.
https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized

Answer (score 1):

If what you're asking is **[ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)**, here are a few tips:

```
0 Black
1 Red
2 Green
3 Yellow/Brown
4 Blue
5 Pink
6 Cyan
7 White/Gray
```

Each of them is applied to foreground, or background color.

```
3_  sets grim    foreground color
9_  sets intense foreground color
4_  sets grim    background color
10_ sets intense background color
# 3-4, 9-10 and a code for a color.
```

For example, by doing `printf "\033[1;44;97m"` you make your background `44` (grim blue) foreground `97` (intense white).

There are other useful color codes you should also use:

```
0 reset all colors
1 bold
3 italics
4 underline
5 blink
7 inverse
```

To make it more comfortable to work with that, you can make a set of aliases like `fiblue` `fred` `bblack` etc. You may also add the following function to your `bashrc`:

```
ansi() {
    printf "\033[$1"
}
```

So that instead of writing `\033[1;35m` you do `ansi '1;35m'`, and writing color aliases with that function is more comfortable.

You should also take a note that setting a background color resets already set foreground color, so you should use **`\033[`***`misc;background;foreground`***`m`**.

This way, you can paint any `PS1` you like. Here's an example:

```
PS1="\033[0;1;36m\u\033[0;1m:\033[1;103;30m\t\033[0m \033[1;92m\$\033[0m \r"
```

Also have a look at **[bash_it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it)**.

Hope I answered what you asked.